# Pronunciation and transcription of the vowel in "fear", "dear", "near" etc

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, vowels, sounds, phonics

I wonder, words like *fear, dear, near* and so on have long *e* in pronunciation, and it should be transcribed as /i:/, but I've found it transcribed as short /ɪ/. Why is that?

Comment: In English, vowel sounds are often altered by a following "r".  The exact nature of this depends on the accent. What accent are you talking about?

Comment: In American English, for instance, the /i/ ~/ɪ/ phonemic distinction, like most tense/lax vowel distinctions, is simply neutralized before /r/. There are no contrasts, so there is near-free variation. Which, of course, means that that variation is probably available for ingroup identification, though I don't know of any studies showing that. Yet.

Comment: Do you think *mirror* and *nearer* rhyme? Most Americans do. So if you are deciding on a system of IPA for American English, you might need to decide whether you  are going to use /ɪ/ or /i:/ for this vowel.

Answer (score 2):

Vowel sounds exist along continuous spectra in several dimensions (front/back, high/low, rounded/unrounded, tense/lax, r-colored, etc.). The symbols we use to denote phonemes or even allophones are points within those spectra. Therefore interpretations will often diverge between transcribers. Furthermore, individual speakers offer a lot of variation in pronunciation due to dialect and idiolect. It is natural to expect some imprecision in a system of single symbols for what amounts to a statistical condensation of wide-ranging individual sounds.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> In American English, for instance, the /i/ ~/ɪ/ phonemic distinction, like most tense/lax vowel distinctions, is simply neutralized before /r/. There are no contrasts, so there is near-free variation. Which, of course, means that that variation is probably available for ingroup identification, though I don't know of any studies showing that. Yet.